# Mongo db query ( express server ) failing via browser request but working on postman ( Not a CORS error )

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

I am facing the following problem on my express application running on Ubuntu 20.04.

I have an express.js server set up with node.js and typescript. I am using mongo db with mongoose.

**PROBLEM**

> While I am sending a request on my server application via the browser
> to login (for example), mongoose function findOne fails and returns
> always null for the retrieved document.
>
> This is not happening via postman !!
>
> ALSO THIS CODE IS RUNNING CORRECTLY ON MY OTHER WINDOWS MACHINE!

**MACHINE SETUP**

> OS: Ubuntu 20.04
>
> Node: 15.11.0
>
> MongoDB Shell: 4.4.4
>
> Mongoose: 5.11.19

**CODE**

```
export const login = async (
    request: Request,
    response: Response,
    next: NextFunction
) => {
    const { error, value } = UserLoginValidation.validate(request.body);

    if (error) {
        const commonError: ICommonError = {
            statusCode: 400,
            message: error.details[0].message
        };
        return response.status(400).json(commonError);
    }

    const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email: value.email })
    console.log(user);

    //HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!! USER IS ALWAYS NULL!!!

    if (!user) {
        const commonError: ICommonError = {
            statusCode: 401,
            message: "Email and password, does not match."
        };
        return response.status(401).json(commonError);
    }

    const match = await compare(value.password, user.password);

    if (!match) {
        const commonError: ICommonError = {
            statusCode: 401,
            message: "Email and password, does not match."
        };
        return response.status(401).json(commonError);
    }

    try {
        const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, <string>process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: "1d" });

        response.setHeader("X-Access-Token", `Bearer ${token}`);

        return response.status(200).send({
            message: 'Login Successful!', user: {
                _id: user._id,
                firstName: user.firstName,
                lastName: user.lastName,
                email: user.email
            }
        })
    } catch (e) {
        const commonError: ICommonError = {
            statusCode: 500,
            message: "Internal Server Error",
            details: e.toString()
        };
        return response.status(500).json(commonError);
    }
};
```

**REQUEST VIA BROWSER**
[image]
**REQUEST VIA POSTMAN**

[image]

**WHAT I HAVE ALREADY TRIED**

> 1. Different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera and MS Edge ) latest versions
> 2. Different node versions (15.11.0, 12.13.0 and 10.18.0)
> 3. Different momgo db versions (4.4.4 and 4.2.11)
> 4. Different mongoose versions (5.11.19 and 5.10.0)
> 5. I have tried to set project folder permissions to 777 via sudo chmod -R 777 /project-folder
> 6. I have also tried to change user ownership via chown to the project folder
> 7. I have tried to verify the request body data and check its type before enter them on the mongoose model.findOne() function.
> 8. Finlay, I have tried to run the same query directly to mongo shell which is responding with the corresponding document instead of null.
>
> I found the problem to be on the mongoose query but I am not able to
> troubleshoot it.

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOR**

> Mongoose query to work properly ( find the user which is already in
> the database ).

Comment: Print out `request.body` value.

Comment: This is the request.body how it looks like:

`{
  email: "anastasios.theodosiou@gmail.com",
  password: "somepassword"
}`